# Delay a bit the Assigned e-mail

Tags: email, tasks

I want to send an Assigned task message to some people. But if we do it by default, it will send the e-mail in the next 5 minutes.

Is there anyway to delay this message for maybe a month and making it repeat and repeat that email month after month?

Answer (score 1):

Hello Geff and welcome to SP.SE

I think you have to create a workflow for that requirement and handle the "reminder" every month there. Out of the box this is **not** possible.

Comment: you think so? thanks for your help.

Comment: More precisely: Delaying assigned task mails is only possible  with workflow. There is out of the box workflow functionality, though.